# Check if a time is between two times and not on a weekend in a certain timezone with moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to execute some code if the current time anywhere in the world is between 8:30 AM and 5:30 PM and is not the weekend in Mountain Standard Time. I'm loading in `moment-with-locales.min.js` and `moment-timezone-with-data.min.js`. My code looks like this:

```
var format = 'hh:mm',
    date = new Date()
    mstWeekday = moment(date, 'd', 'MST')
    time = moment(date, format),
    beforeTime = moment('08:30', format, 'MST'),
    afterTime = moment('17:30', format, 'MST');

if ( (time.isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime)) && ( (mstWeekday !== 6) || (mstWeekday !== 7) ) ) {
  // Do something
}
```

If my browser is set to MST, this seems to work. If I set it to something else, like Tokyo time, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing (didn't even need moment.js):

```
    var beforeTime = 1430; // 8:30 AM MST in UTC
    var afterTime = 2330; // 5:30 PM MST in UTC

    var date = new Date();
    var currentHours = date.getUTCHours();
    var currentMinutes = leadingZero(date.getUTCMinutes());
    var currentTime = parseInt('' + currentHours + currentMinutes); // Make 24 hour (0000)    

    var currentDayMst = date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Edmonton"}); // Get current day of week in MST
        currentDayMst = new Date(currentDayMst);
        currentDayMst = currentDayMst.getDay();

    // If not between 8:30am and 5:30pm OR Saturday OR Sunday, do stuff
    if ( !( (currentTime >= beforeTime) && (currentTime <= afterTime) ) || (currentDay == 6) || (currentDay == 0) ) {
      // Do stuff
    }   

    function leadingZero (i) {
      if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
      }
      return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using moment-timezone for timezone related ops

The following might help you

```
const moment = require("moment-timezone");
var beforeTime = moment.tz("08:30", "hh-mm", "MST");
var afterTime = moment.tz("17:30", "hh-mm", "MST");
var date = moment("21-03-2020");
var mstWeekday = moment(date, "d", "MST");
if (
  date.isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime) &&
  (mstWeekday !== 6 || mstWeekday !== 7)
) {
  console.log("in here");
}
```

Comment: I need to pull the exact time the user is on the page, so I changed the date var to moment(); This still isn't resolving correctly though. If I put my browser in Tokyo time and check at 9am MST, the if statement doesn't execute. If I switch to MST however, it does execute